# Mysql not insert records

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: `employee` and `employee_group`. After insert to first table I will get last inserted id from this table. Next I need insert to table `employee_group`. SQL:

```
INSERT INTO employee_group (employee_id, group_id) 
  SELECT {$currentEmpId}, group_id 
  FROM employee_group 
  WHERE employee_id = {$anyId}
```

MySQL has been returned TRUE. But records have not inserted.

I noticed if try insert records for previous inserted employee then query will be successful. Example:

1. Insert to employee, will return `$currentEmpId` as last inserted id
2. `INSERT INTO employee_group (employee_id, group_id) SELECT {$currentEmpId - 1}, group_id FROM employee_group WHERE employee_id = {$anyEmpId}`

Or if I tried insert records for current employee and previous at the same time then first query will be unsuccessful but second query ok.

The database has not triggers, foreign keys or functions. Nothing, just data.

I'm in a deadlock.

UPD: If I take records to php variable then foreach it and insert each record as one item like `INSERT INTO employee_group (employee_id, group_id) VALUES (xxx, yyy)` I will get this problem too.

Comment: `{$currentEmpId - 1}` is going to cause a PHP syntax error, and definitley cause an sql syntax error.

Comment: I'm sorry for that code, really there is `sprintf(".. SELECT %u ..", $currentEmpId - 1)` but I have replaced it to better understand .

Comment: Your successful INSERT uses `{$anyEmpId}`, but the failing one uses `{$anyId}`. Which is the correct variable?

Comment: The {$anyEmpId} and {$anyId} is correct both. For test I took another variables names than for "production" query. The problem not with empty or incorrect input vars, there all is ok. The problem with insert to `employee_group` records with `employee_id = <last inserted id of employee>`. If I try assign to `employee_id` not last inserted id but previous or future id I will succesfull do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO employee_group (employee_id, group_id) 
  VALUES({$toEmpId},{SELECT group_id FROM employee_group WHERE employee_id = {$fromEmpId}})
```

Check it out ..

Comment: I am not sure what mysql allow insert many records from other table by this way. I have tried your sql but have got a syntax error.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO employee_group (employee_id, group_id) 
  VALUES({$toEmpId},{SELECT {$toEmpId}, group_id FROM employee_group WHERE employee_id = {$fromEmpId}})
```

Comment: You're trying to insert 3 values into 2 columns here.

Comment: That is soOoOooooooo not going to work....3 values into a 2 fields, and I don't know how you expect a select to work in there, plus those extra {} are a syntax error, etc... etc... etc...